# Run selenium webdrivers from applet in HTML

Tags: java, html, selenium, applet, webdriver

I need to invoke Selenium from Client Side, so I'm trying to run Selenium from a Java Applet in a static HTML page.

I'm using firefox 3.6.12 in SUSE Linux environment. 
The HTML page looks like this

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
</HEAD> 
<BODY> 
<APPLET ALIGN="CENTER" CODE="SeleniumTest.class" WIDTH="800" 
HEIGHT="500" archive="/home/******/Selenium/selenium-2.20.0/selenium- 
server-standalone-2.20.0.jar,/home/******/Selenium/selenium-2.20.0/ 
selenium-java-2.20.0.jar,/home/*******/Selenium/selenium-2.20.0/ 
selenium-firefox-driver-2.0a5.jar" ></APPLET> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

The Applet was loaded and info statements were printed. But, during 
the creation of webdriver, I'm getting the below exception in Java 
Console and it stops there.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-8" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable 
        at 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java: 
56) 
        at 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java: 
52) 
        at 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java: 
84) 
        at SeleniumTest.getWebDriver(SeleniumTest.java:36) 
        at SeleniumTest.runTest(SeleniumTest.java:85) 
        at SeleniumTest.paint(SeleniumTest.java:23) 
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.awt.X11.XRepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.awt.X11.XComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source) 
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown 
Source) 
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) 
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown 
Source) 
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have added the 'selenium-firefox-driver-2.0a5.jar' to my 'archive' 
attribute of Applet declaration in HTML.

Is applet capable of doing such operations ? (Since, it uses JVM, I guess it should be)

What else should I do to overcome this issue ?

Is there any work-around to start selenium from browser other than using java applets ?

PS: When I try to run the Applet alone in eclipse, it works fine. But, I get this problem when I open it in browser.

Comment: "*Is there any work-around to start selenium from browser other than using java applets ?"*  Yes, and far better.  It is [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It launches a frame for a link.  But you'll need to sort the class-path either way.  BTW - since `/home/*******/Selenium/selenium-2.20.0/` seems a common root to all the Jars, it'd be better to specify it as the `codebase`.

Comment: I would think you'll have to add all the required libs to the archive, too.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try with Java web start and see how it goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Signed Applets solved the issue.

Reference: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm