# Does init support apps with Selenium Jars?

Tags: java, selenium, init

Is it possible to embed a Java app that has Selenium code lines into a web browser? Is this supported or not?

I have a Java application that uses Selenium API. I tried to use the init() method to embed the GUI window into a browser so that the application could be launched from a website, however it did not work. Is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: I am not sure, but may be `java applets` is what you can try.

Comment: "I tried to use the init() method..."  Where?  You need to give more details about what you are attempting. But an applet is the only way to run Java code from a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can because the selenium java client is just an java app that interacts with selenium grid in [JsonWire](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) protocol.

Take a look at this question [Run selenium webdrivers from applet in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944305/run-selenium-webdrivers-from-applet-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. You cannot launch such an app from a web browser